# Else without If error for multiple events

Tags: vba, excel

I'm going around the houses here and can't see the wood for the trees. I keep getting this Else without If error but cannot fix it. The answers I found on here I cannot get to work for me (I'm sure because I missing something obvious). Any help to point me in the correct direction will be much appreciated.
First bit of code to hide/unhide an additional sheet works on its own but when I add another to change the font colour of certain cells depending on LoB it breaks?
Thanks in advance
Code below:

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = Me.Range("LoB").Address Then
If Target.Value = "AVIATION" Then
        Sheets("Aviation Debit Summary").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("Aviation Debit Summary").Visible = False
    Else
If Target.Address = Me.Range("LoB").Address Then
If Target.Value = "MARINE" Then
        Range("C54:E55").Select
    With Selection.Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You can only have one `Else` clause within an `If` block. Perhaps you mean to use an `ElseIf` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an `end if` after `Sheets("Aviation Debit Summary").Visible = False`
, and an `end with` after `.TintAndShade = 0`

try this

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("LoB") = "AVIATION" Then
    Sheets("Aviation Debit Summary").Visible = True
Else
    Sheets("Aviation Debit Summary").Visible = False
End If

If Range("LoB") = "MARINE" Then
    With Range("C54:E55").Font
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
Else
    With Range("C54:E55").Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much ballsy26, that's stopped the error coming up but the last half of the code (to change the font colour if "Marine") does not want to work. What have I done wrong? Thanks

Comment: what colour are you trying to change it to?

Comment: Basically if the "LoB" is "Marine" then I want it to be white (so in effect not visible) or Black if "LoB" is anything else

Comment: as in the text is white or the cell background?

Comment: Sorry, yes the text to White

Comment: You need to learn to indent code mate. That indentation is terrible to read with nested ifs. Here is how you should do it: https://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~pjbk/pathways/cpp1/node99.html (first example shows how to have nested ifs)

Comment: i changed a bit with your code. check the answer for the update.

Comment: Ballsy26 that works perfectly! I can't thank you enough for your help.

Comment: CyberClaw, thanks very much for the link mate. That's a really useful guide to help me improve

Comment: Just an update. I managed to break this code by protecting my spreadsheet! If you make the same error I did you just need to add 'ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("")' at the beginning and 'ActiveSheet.Protect ("")' at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The same for this colour changing could be completed with using conditional formatting on the range you're wanting Alt + O D D (if I remember correctly!), then you wouldn't have to code that part.